# Terraform local-exec to pass new resource( not hard-coding)

Tags: terraform

I'm executing a bash script using terraform. My null_resource configuration code is given below

```
resource "null_resource" "mytest" {

triggers = {
    run = "${timestamp()}"
 }

 provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "sh test.sh"

 }
 }
```

Let us take git repo as an example resource. I'm doing  bunch of operations using the batch script on the resource. This resource names are passed using terraform.tfvars

```
resource_list = ["RS1","RS2","RS3","RS4"]
```

If I want to add a new repo named RS5 then I can update the the above list by adding RS5 to it.

How I will pass the new resource name to the batch script. **Here I'm not looking to hard code the parameter as given below**

```
sh test.sh "RS5"
```

How i will pass the most recent resource to the batch script?

Comment: Do you want to execute the command once per element of the resource list?

Comment: no @MattSchuchard
i want to run the command only for the newly added resource

Comment: So you want to access the last element of `var.resource_list` and interpolate it in the string for the value of the `command` argument?

Comment: what is the intended purpose of `timestamp()`?

Comment: @pkatsourakis When I removed the resource from target , and when i run the apply command at that time the local-exec provisioner is not running. That is the reason i kept the timestamp() . Is there any other way to run this when i manually delete the resource from target and when i run the apply command it should create the resource again and run the script. But now it is just creating the resources but the script is not running

Comment: When you manually delete resources terraform has no way to know that you did that, so it doesn't re-create the resource. Instead of manually deleting, you can use a [destroy-time provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#destroy-time-provisioners) and use `terraform destroy` to delete resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) to execute the batch script once per resource in the resource_list variable

```
resource "null_resource" "mytest" {
  for_each = toset(var.resource_list)

  # using timestamp() will cause the script to run again for every value on 
  # every run since the value changes every time. 
  # you probably don't want that behavior.

  # triggers = {
  #  run = "${timestamp()}"
  # }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sh test.sh ${each.value}"
  }
}
```

When you run this the first time it will execute the script once for each of the resources in `resource_list`. Then the terraform state file will be updated to know what has already run, so any subsequent runs will only include new items added to `resource_list`.

Comment: Calling `timestamp` inside `triggers` will prevent this resource from ever converging though, so in practice Terraform will plan to re-create all of these resource instances every time, regardless of how `var.resource_list` changed. It wasn't clear to me from the question whether that was important, so I'm just noting it here fore completeness.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error @MartinAtkins. I added a comment in the code to emphasize that point. I would suggest to take `triggers` out of the code as part of the solution to the question.

Comment: @MartinAtkins and pkasourakis
Could any one of you please help with the below question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651591/terraform-null-resource-not-running-with-backend

Comment: @pkatsourakis and Martin
Could any one of you please help with the below question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651591/terraform-null-resource-not-running-with-backend