# Terraform null_resource not running with backend

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a terraform variable map of objects as given below

```
variable "MyProj" {
  type = map(object({
  name     = string
  type     = string
 }))
default = {
  "Proj1" = {
      name      = "Proj1"
      programme = "java"
   },
   "Proj2" = {
      name       = "Proj2"
      programme  = "npm"
  }
 }
}
```

I also have a null resource code that will run a batch script whenever change is identified based on the above map(objects()) and desired state.

```
   resource "null_resource" "nullr" {
   for_each = var.MyProj

   provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "bash /home/myscript.sh ${each.value.name} ${each.value.progrmme}
  }
}
```

My intention is that whenever a change is identified in the above map() then the null resource should run.

This is running as expected when I keep the terraform state in my local machine. But when I keep the terraform state in a Azure blob container using azurem backend it is not running the null_resource.
What change I should do in the configuration even if I use a backend for terraform state

Comment: You certainly need to specify the `triggers` property. Otherwise a null_resource never runs again.

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you.
But it is running fine when I keep the state locally. Only issue is when I keep the state in azurerm backend. I don't want to run null_resource always. Since I'm using  for_each it will run differently as per the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349022/terraform-local-exec-to-pass-new-resource-not-hard-coding/69351759#:~:text=When%20you%20run%20this%20the%20first%20time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to start here by saying that it *seems* like what you are doing here might be outside of Terraform's typical scope: usually tools like `npm` belong to the "build" step of a build/deploy pipeline, and Terraform isn't really intended or designed to deal with that family of use-cases. Since it's a general programmable tool you can of course make it do things outside of its scope if you are creative, but it usually comes with caveats and limitations.

I'm going to attempt to answer your question as you wrote it but I'd also suggest thinking more philosophically about whether it would be better to solve whatever problem this is intended to solve using a separate process that runs before Terraform in a pipeline, or if perhaps the entire problem would be better solved by some other system that's explicitly designed to support build and deploy processes.

---

The `null_resource` resource type is a special "escape hatch" in Terraform that intentionally does nothing so that you can attach provisioners to it that wouldn't otherwise naturally belong to a resource. The intended purpose of provisioners (although [as a last resort](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#provisioners-are-a-last-resort)) is to implement additional steps that a particular object needs carried out in order to become fully operational, such as writing some needed data into a virtual machine's filesystem.

Normal resource types have inherent rules defined by the remote system about what sorts of changes can be applied in-place and what sorts of changes require re-creating the object. Because `null_resource` represents no particular remote object type, it doesn't have any such *inherent* rules, but it does have the more artificial concept of a `triggers` argument that does nothing except force replacing the object whenever its value differs from the previous run.

In order to force your `null_resource` to be replaced and therefore to force its associated provisioners to re-run then will require populating the `triggers` argument with values that will normally stay unchanged but that should, if changed, cause the provisioner to re-run.

In your case it seems like the values within your `var.MyProj` might be a reasonable thing to use as triggers, though because `triggers` is a map of strings we'd need to encode it to a string first. JSON encoding could be a reasonable answer in that case:

```
resource "null_resource" "nullr" {
  for_each = var.MyProj

  triggers = {
    settings = jsonencode(each.value)
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "bash /home/myscript.sh ${each.value.name} ${each.value.progrmme}
  }
}
```

Because the `triggers` for each instance of the resource only refers to the current `each.value`, adding a new entry to `var.MyProj` should not affect any of the existing instances of the resource, and thus not re-run any provisioners. However, if you edit one of the existing keys then it will re-run with the new settings.

If you expect to need to re-run a particular resource's provisioner even though neither its name or "progrmme" have changed then you may wish to add a third attribute to the element type of `var.MyProj` which is an integer or some special string identifier that you'll change each time it needs to re-run. You could then change the value of that attribute to force it to re-run even though it'll be re-running the same program as before.

Another situation to consider is what should happen if the content of this `myscript.sh` changes. If you want to re-run the script each time it changes then you can add another `triggers` entry to capture a checksum of the file, which will therefore change each time the file changes:

```
resource "null_resource" "nullr" {
  for_each = var.MyProj

  triggers = {
    settings        = jsonencode(each.value)
    script_checksum = filesha256("/home/myscript.sh")
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "bash /home/myscript.sh ${each.value.name} ${each.value.progrmme}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin.

But my logic is working perfectly when I'm using a local tfstate file and going wrong when I use an azurerm backend for tfstate. Are you aware of any such limitation when using a remote state file?

Comment: my actual requirement  is posted in the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69682098/modify-the-source-files-before-doing-terraform-git-import

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there- you have a script, a null resource, and a well defined change that you want to trigger the null resource.

First, build your trigger string. If you expect it to be particularly large, the `md5` function can help, but having it be human readable makes it easier to debug:

```
locals {
  script_trigger = join(", ", 
    [ for projKey, ProjObj in var.MyProj
      : "${projKey}(${join(", ", 
        [for key, value in projObj
          : "${key}=${value}"])})" 
    ]
  )
}
```

Then, add that string to your triggers:

```
resource "null_resource" "nullr" {
  ...
  triggers = { project_object = locals.script_trigger }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dan.
But I'm getting an error here
locals.tf line 3: Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item.

Comment: Fixed it. Started writing a python-style for statement, apologies.

Comment: Thank you @Dan. But the problem with this approach is even if we delete the Proj2 from the map at that time also it will run the configuration against Proj1  as described in the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349022/terraform-local-exec-to-pass-new-resource-not-hard-coding/69351759#:~:text=Calling%20timestamp%20inside,here%20fore%20completeness.