# Modify the source files before doing Terraform git import

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I have a terraform code to create one repository by importing from another parent repository.
The below code is working perfectly and I'm able to import the repo.

```
 resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_generic_git" "serviceendpoint" {
  project_id            = azuredevops_project.project.id
  repository_url        = "https://{ORG}@dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{Proj}/_git/newrepo"
  username              = "test"
  password              = "PAT"
  service_endpoint_name = "Sample Generic Git"
  description           = "Managed by Terraform"
  }

 resource "azuredevops_git_repository" "reponew" {
 project_id = azuredevops_project.project.id
 name       = "newrepo"
 initialization {
   init_type             = "Import"
   source_type           = "Git"
   source_url            = "https://{ORG}@dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{Proj}/_git/parentrepo"
  service_connection_id = azuredevops_serviceendpoint_generic_git.serviceendpoint.id
}
}
```

But my requirement is to modify some files  before importing to the newrepo. I was using null_resource for this purpose. But it is facing some issue as described in
[Terraform null_resource not running with backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651591/terraform-null-resource-not-running-with-backend/69679841#69679841)

How we could modify some files before importing using Terraform?

Comment: Maybe something like `local-exec`: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html?

Answer (score 1):

You can make changes ( commit) using `azuredevops_git_repository_file` construct. `content` attribute  can be of type file or string.

```
resource "azuredevops_git_repository_file" "repo_file" {
  repository_id       = azuredevops_git_repository.reponew.id
  file                = "README.MD"
  content             = file("templates/localfile") 
  branch              = "refs/heads/master"
  commit_message      = "Update commit"
  overwrite_on_create = false
}
```